# ObservableCollection not binding to combo box

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Just wondering as to why my ObservableCollection is not binding to my Combo Box
I don't get any errors it just doesn't populate it.

```
public class TableList : ObservableCollection<TableName>
{
    public TableList() : base()
    {
        Add(new TableName(1, "Notes"));
        Add(new TableName(2, "TemplateNotes"));
    }
}

public class TableName
{
    private int noteID;
    private string noteName;

    public TableName(int ID, string name)
    {
        this.noteID = ID;
        this.noteName = name;
    }

    public int NoteID
    {
        get { return noteID; }
        set { noteID = value; }
    }

    public string NoteName
    {
        get { return noteName; }
        set { noteName = value; }
    }
}
```

This is my XAML

```
<ComboBox 
    x:Name="noteSaveToSelection" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Height="35" 
    Margin="155,932,0,0" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    Width="180" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding TableList}" 
    DisplayMemberPath="NoteName" 
    SelectedValuePath="NoteID"/>
```

I am new to this so i apologise if i have missed something small.

Comment: have you checked the output window for binding issues?

Comment: also try something like Snoop to inspect the UI and see what it is actually bound to

Comment: It seems to be bound to TablesList but the collection is TableList. Can you check? If not works, can you post the property in code to which you have bound the combo?

Comment: `TableList` is a type, but you bind to the property (of that type, I guess). Can you show us the property?

Comment: Just noticed, i bound to TablesList with an 's' i have removed that and still isn't working. @slawekwin isn't the Type TableName? Sorry, im quite new to C#

Comment: Try binding `ObservableCollection<TableName> YourCollection`  and ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollection}"

Comment: @Luke that is exactly the point. You bind to properties in your view-model, not to types

Comment: @LukeLitherland You have TableList defined as ObservableCollection. So if you have a property named TableListProperty(for example) of Type TableList in your codebehind/ViewModel, then it should work i.e. public TableList TableListProperty {get;set;} in your class. in UI ItemsSource="{Binding TableListProperty}"

Comment: Are you trying to learn MVVM? Try to create a simple ViewModel with a string type property and then try to bind it to your view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently you never create an instance of your TableList class that you can actually bind to.

Create a view model class with a `TableList` property, e.g. like

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public TableList TableList { get; } = new TableList();
}
```

Then set the `DataContext` property of your MainWindow to an instance of the view model class:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new ViewModel();
}
```

Comment: Oh ok i'll give that a go, i was following this [How to: Create and Bind to an ObservableCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748365(v=vs.110).aspx) To get to where i am now

Comment: You could also go without the ViewModel class and directly assign `DataContext = new TableList();`. Then the binding would be written without a Path: `ItemsSource="{Binding}"`.

Comment: Thank you this worked without the view model (im sure with would as well, but i tried without and it worked)